# Bring Back Old App Launcher

Tags: launcher, 21.04, 21.10

I have updated from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 and I don't like the new App Launcher. I want to bring back the launcher that darkened my background and put the virtual desktops on the sides instead of on the top. How do I do it?

Comment: You can't. Ubuntu 21.10 uses GNOME 40, which has a new design. If you don't want such frequent changes, either stick to the LTS releases, or use another DE (e.g. XFCE) that stays the same over years.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the GNOME desktop; and Ubuntu 21.10 uses the GNOME 40 desktop, instead of GNOME 3.38 found with Ubuntu 21.04. The changes were made by the GNOME developers, in what they believe provide a better user experience for the future.  You could always install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS & use the older GNOME 3.36 desktop (*you can re-install without losing data files; just use a re-install method where you don't format your partition(s)*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.10 uses Gnome Shell 40. That version of Gnome changed from vertical to horizontal workspaces. A Gnome Shell extension, [Vertical overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4144/vertical-overview/) by Ralthuis allows to bring back the old layout.

The background of the overview now is black by default. If you want to revert to an effect where you see your desktop darkened, you can use the extension [Blur my Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3193/blur-my-shell/) by aunetx.

Comment: It works but it does not make the background transparent.

Comment: There is another extension that can do that. See my edited answer.